# What is localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Could someone please explain to me what `localStorage` is, and how or where I would use it?

I realise this question can be answered by "Googling", but I prefer the concise, easy to find, well index & diverse opinionated answers that I get from Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you know where to look, go there and look.

Comment: How is this question different to these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+is

Comment: The MDN page is a little shorter but more generic, if it matters that much to you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#Description

Comment: @Andre: Those questions are five years old

Answer (score 8, accepted):

localStorage is a way to store data on the client's computer. Let's say you want to save the date the last time a user visited your webpage. You can use the following code once the page loads:

```
function saveData() {
  localStorage.lasttimevisited = new Date();
}
```

The next time the page loads you can check if `localStorage.lasttimevisited` is full and if it is, welcome the user.

The advantages to localStorage is that it will still be in memory **even when you close the browser.** If somebody visits that page, they will get a welcome from last time (if they visited last time) even if the last time they visited was centuries ago.

However, there are some disadvantages. The user can **clear the browser data/cache** to erase all localStorage data. They can also have an unsupported browser, such as IE7.

localStorage can only be accessed via JavaScript, and is HTML5.